# HOW to update and display JSON file dynamically on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, firefox-addon

I am creating an addon in which, on click of a toolbar button, a panel is displayed which contains checkboxes and a save button. On clicking the save button, the selected checkbox`s data  should be saved/updated in a JSON file which should be displayed after clicking save.
Moreover, the data dynamically updated in JSON file should be available even after browser restart. 
   Also the JSON file should be saved in file system or local storage?
Is this possible.. plz help... And plz ask if u need more info. Below is the addonScript which I used:-

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var text_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("CheckboxAddon.html"),
  //contentScriptFile: data.url("my-script.js")
});

// button creation
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "show-panel",
  label: "Show Panel",
  icon: {
    "16": "./star-icon.png",
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

// Show the panel when the user clicks the button.
function handleClick(state) {
  text_entry.show();
}
text_entry.on("show", function() {
  text_entry.port.emit("show");
});
text_entry.port.on("text-entered", function (text) {
  console.log(text);
  text_entry.hide();
});
```

Comment: totally possible, you're looking for the firefox webstorage api.  are you also having trouble creating the json files?

Comment: yes m having the trouble creating json file. Btwn is my approach right? or do i need to do some changes in the code..?

Comment: looks good so far, I'll take a closer look and get back to u on the json a bit later today

Comment: sorry for the delay.  Just to be clear, you're looking to show a textual representation of the JSON object?

Comment: if the answer isn't helpful let me know, I might have misunderstood where you were going wrong

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to keep in mind is that JSON is a subset of javascript, so you just write a javascript object which is also valid JSON.  In your case I doubt this is going to be something you'll have to be worrying about.  to achieve the effect you're looking for you can simply throw whatever data into `dataString = JSON.stringify(data)` or `dataString = JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t")` to give it that json format look. Conversely you would use `JSON.parse(dataString)` to turn a string into a javascript object.

Definitely use the [json.org documentation](http://www.json.org/js.html) a guide for writing JSON objects yourself.

the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) has good examples, look at the JSON.stringify and JSON.parse in the methods section